# Intent chooser is shown with NFC TECH_DISCOVERED filter and foreground dispatch system

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc, intentfilter

Since I changed my NFC foreground dispatch registration to use the `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter, I keep having to choose between multiple applications to process the NFC tag. Is there a way to directly receive the NFC intent in my app when a tag is discovered?

```
public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter[] mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {
            ndef
    };
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, mFilters, null);
}

public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent filter requires a tech-list. Consequently, your current foreground-dispatch registration does not listen for any tag technologies at all.

When you register that intent filter through the manifest, you would use

```
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
           android:resource="@xml/nfc_tag_filter" />
```

to do that. Similarly, when you register for the foreground dispatch with the `enableForegroundDispatch()` method, you need to specify a tech-list (an array of string arrays) in the last argument of `enableForegroundDispatch()`. E.g. to listen for all possible tag technologies (i.e. NFC-A or NFC-B or NFC-F or NFC-V or NFC-Barcode), you would use:

```
IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[] {
        new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED),
};
String[][] techList = new String[][] {
        new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcB.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcV.class.getName() },
        new String[] { NfcBarcode.class.getName() },
};
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
```

Note that if you want to filter for any tag through the foreground dispatch system, you can also simply use the catch-all foreground dispatch:

```
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

However, be aware that a `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent will be delivered to your app in that case.